# BadZipFile Error only when I'm using variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import io
import zipfile


def right():
    file = io.BytesIO()
    zipfile.ZipFile(file, "w").writestr("test.txt", "test string")

    file.seek(0)
    zipfile.ZipFile(file, "r")


def wrong():
    file = io.BytesIO()
    zipping_file = zipfile.ZipFile(file, "w")
    zipping_file.writestr("test.txt", "test string")

    file.seek(0)
    zipfile.ZipFile(file, "r")


right()
print("right ok")
wrong()  # BadZipFile Error here!!
print("wrong ok")
```

I've tried it on python 3.9 and 3.7.9. I can't understand why `right()` function is not throwing it. There should be absolutely no difference between these two approaches, shouldn't it?

Comment: The `right` one allows garbage collection (and other cleanup) earlier. With the `wrong` one, when the `ZipFile` object is closed is undefined.

Comment: Try adding an explicit `close()` call to the `wrong` one before the seek. And tell me if it works so I can add an answer; this isn't an answer now because I'm on my phone and can't test.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Great catch, adding `zipping_file.close()` to `wrong()` makes it work :o. I still don't unerstand why is `close()` called silently..

Comment: ...re: "why `close()` is called silently" -- I'd hazard that `__del__()` calls it when a ZipFile is still open while it's being finalized.

Comment: ...and indeed it does: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6086ae7fd4aeb4089282189673f9bd0cc33abf9b/Lib/zipfile.py#L1806-L1808

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Greetings!. I have been your follower and I request your support here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405460/what-should-we-do-when-one-person-tries-to-delete-every-duplicate/406140#406140 as we are trying curb abuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `right()`, there's no reference to the first `ZipFile` instance after the line where the `writestr()` happens, so it's eligible to be finalized ([calling `__del__`, which in turn calls `close()` when that wasn't done already](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6086ae7fd4aeb4089282189673f9bd0cc33abf9b/Lib/zipfile.py#L1806-L1808)) immediately. (Zip files have an footer at the end of the file that maintains pointers to their content; updating this index during a close operation is typical). Note that Python-the-language-spec doesn't *force* implementations to garbage-collect and finalize the object immediately on deletion of the last reference, so some Python implementations could choose to defer this -- it's not guaranteed to run the way you want on all possible language implementations, and if you checked Jython/PyPy/IronPython/etc., there's a chance one would misbehave.

With `wrong()`, because there's a reference held, the `zipping_file` *cannot* be finalized and thus implicitly closed until the end of the function, so it never gets its footer written.

Just do an explicit `close()` to fix this:

```
def formerly_wrong():
    file = io.BytesIO()
    zipping_file = zipfile.ZipFile(file, "w")
    zipping_file.writestr("test.txt", "test string")
    zipping_file.close()

    file.seek(0)
    zipfile.ZipFile(file, "r")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've found out (with my colleague's help) `ZipFile.__del__` is calling `.close` on a file - probably that's the thing.