# why pool.connection().cursor().execute() is a warning operation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dbutils

I'm new to python and learning DB operation with `DBUtils`. Why pool.connection().cursor().execute() would release the connection too early for reuse?

> If you don't need it any more, you should immediately return it to the
> pool with db.close(). You can get another connection in the same way.
>
> **Warning: In a threaded environment, never do the following:**
>
> **pool.connection().cursor().execute(...)**
>
> This would release the connection too early for reuse which may be
> fatal if the connections are not thread-safe. Make sure that the
> connection object stays alive as long as you are using it, like that:
>
> db = pool.connection()
>
> cur = db.cursor()
>
> cur.execute(...)
>
> res = cur.fetchone()
>
> cur.close()  # or del cur
>
> db.close()  # or del db

Comment: You have to keep a reference to the connection (in the example: `db`) as long as you want to use it. This will make sure it is not cleaned up.

Comment: This is very similar to a (non-dbutils-based) question I ran across recently with the same style of lifecycle issues (except in reverse, when the lifecycle being too _long_ was a problem): [BadZipFile only when I'm using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66673656/badzipfile-error-only-when-im-using-variable)

Comment: Basically, though, in this case: Once the connection is closed, `fetchone()` will no longer work. So you can't let the connection become unreferenced until _after_ you actually retrieved the data you want.